# Why doesn't my constructor work? (Java)

Tags: java, oop, selenium, constructor

I have the following class implementation

```
public class PublisherHashMap
{
     private static HashMap<Integer, String> x;

     public PublisherHashMap()
     {
         x.put(0, "www.stackoverflow.com");
     }
}
```

In my test function, I am unable to create an object for some reason.

```
@Test
void test()
{ 
   runTest();
}

public static void runTest()
{
    PublisherHashMap y = new PublisherHashMap();
}
```

EDIT: I didn't construct the HashMap.

Comment: Create the `HashMap`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are attempting to use `x`, the private `HashMap`, before it has been constructed. Hence you need to construct it first. You may do this by any of the following:

1) In the constructor:

```
x = new HashMap<Integer, String>(); 
// or diamond type  
x = new HashMap<>();
```

2) In the class as a field of this class:

```
private static HashMap<Integer, String> x = new HashMap<>();
```

3) In the initializer block:

```
static { 
    x = new HashMap<>();
}
// or the no-static block
{
    x = = new HashMap<>();
}
```

Comment: I'd like to adjoin that the `static` modifier does not really make sense as the attribute is instantiated inside the constructor.

Comment: @home, you're right, but this's one of the ways initialization

Answer (score 2):

You must change your declaration from

```
private static HashMap<Integer, String> x;
```

to

```
private static HashMap<Integer, String> x = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```